# How can I tell what elevation level I am at?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing survival in Minecraft Pocket edition ( v 0.7.6).  I started digging a hole straight down (don't worry, I have ladders with me) and I am curious to what elevation I am at.  Is there anyway to do this or do I need to make craft something to get that information?

[image]

I see there is a chat page I can open, but I am not sure if commands work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current moment in Minecraft Pocket Edition the only way to tell elevation is digging down to bedrock.